# system call: argument don't passed into function

Tags: c, linux

I write a system call function and test it by using kernel modules.

This is my procedure:

1. build the kernel (get mod.ko)
2. `sudo insmod mod.ko`
3. write test c file

firstly, I found out that number 336 is free for system call, therefore I use 336 as offset, hooked my function into sys_call_table:

```
static int __init init_addsyscall(void)
{
    printk("My syscall is starting...\n");
    sys_call_table = (unsigned long *)0xffffffffaae002c0;
    printk("sys_call_table: 0x%p\n", sys_call_table);
    anything_saved = (int(*)(void))(sys_call_table[__NR_syscall]);  /* save original one */
    orig_cr0 = clear_and_return_cr0();  /* make cr0 writable */
    sys_call_table[__NR_syscall] = (unsigned long)&sys_mycall;  /* change function pointer */
    setback_cr0(orig_cr0);  /* recover cr0 */
    return 0;
}
```

my system call is:

```
asmlinkage long sys_mycall(unsigned long long num)
{
    printk("my call, num = %llu", num);
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        return num % 1000000;
    else
        return num % 100000;
}
```

my test c file:

```
// t.c
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",syscall(336, 19030123456));
    return 0;
}
```

It is expected that `t.c` will print `123456`, but it print a random number. I have tried many times to run this test function and got different return-value each times. I use `sudo dmesg` to check the log and can sure that my system call is called, and the argument of system call is not my input as well. It is more likely that the argument is a random number...

```
[ 9444.176815] My syscall is starting...
[ 9444.176825] sys_call_table: 0x000000002dac30a7
[ 9448.550544] my call, num: 18446667112225996632
[ 9449.256182] my call, num: 18446667112224440152
[ 9449.966801] my call, num: 18446667112225046360
[ 9453.252192] my call, num: 18446667112225177432
[ 9455.373322] my call, num: 18446667112225308504
```

I am a beginner and I don't sure what's happening here, and can be sure which information is necessary for analysis. If you need more details, just let me know.

Comment: In the `printk` call in `sys_mycall`, why are you formatting the `unsigned long long` `num` using `%d`? Does it use different conversions than the regular `printf`, or should you use `%llu` for `unsigned long long`? I am not familiar with working inside the Linux kernel, but: Is your `sys_mycall` passed an `unsigned long long`? Is it known to return a `long`? What type does `syscall` return? If it is a `long` as your `sys_mycall` returns, why are you formatting it in `printf` with `%d` rather than `%ld`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil `printk` does mostly use the same as printf (the exceptions are: no float support, extra modifiers for the `%p` format and log level support). The right specifiers in printk are described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html#printk-specifiers).

Comment: @EricPostpischil sorry for the mistake. That's a small mistake because I try to use `int`, `long` ,`unsigned long`, `long long` and `unsigned long long` to test my code. I edit it wrong here and I have fixed it. Actually, `unsigned long long` is the argument's type, and return ` long` because it is in the range of `long`(also in `int`). The key point of the problem is that argument seems not the value that I passed into it(bacause same argument, different `num` in the function).